# How to name dataframe in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to call a dataframe but it's named with a number because it was originally multiple. I want to either rename the dataframes in my loop or find a way to call my dataframe even though it is titled with a number. Right now, after I run this code:

```
filenames <- list.files(path = "filepath",pattern = ".*txt")
head(filenames)

names <- substr(filenames,1,22)

for(i in names){
  filepath <-file.path("filepath",paste(i,".txt",sep = ""))
  assign(i,read.delim(filepath,colClasses = c('character','character','factor','factor'),sep = "\t"))
  }
```

I get a lot of separate dataframes with names like '101_1b1_Al_sc_Meditron.txt'. When I try to even view the dataframe, R is confused because the name begins with a number.

Is there a good solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to reference the original names using backticks.

example:

```
`123_mtcars` <- mtcars
View(`123_mtcars`)
```

If you would prefer to create a naming convention or just to remove numbers from each dataframe name you could do that in your loop and use the new variable in your assign statement.

example:

```
filenames <- list.files(path = "filepath",pattern = ".*txt")
head(filenames)

names <- substr(filenames,1,22)

for(i in names){
    filepath <-file.path("filepath",paste(i,".txt",sep = ""))
    
    # gsub to replace all numbers with "" for the name i
    dfName <- gsub("[0-9]", "", i)
    
    assign(dfName,read.delim(filepath,colClasses = c('character','character','factor','factor'),sep = "\t"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The are 3 solutions I can think of :

**1. Keeping your code in current state.**

If we don't change anything about your code and your dataframes are named as `'101_1b1_Al_sc_Meditron'` to view the contents of the dataframe you can use backticks. Try using it like this :

```
`101_1b1_Al_sc_Meditron`
```

**2. Change the name of dataframes.**

In your loop change the `assign` line to

```
assign(paste0('df_', i), read.delim(filepath,
       colClasses = c('character','character','factor','factor'),sep = "\t"))
```

So after running `for` loop you'll have filenames as `df_101_1b1_Al_sc_Meditron` which is a standard name and you can access them without any problem.

**3. Store data in a list.**

Instead of having so many dataframes in the global environment why not store them in a list. Lists are easier to manage.

```
list_of_files <-lapply(filepath, function(x) read.delim(x, 
      colClasses = c('character','character','factor','factor'),sep = "\t"))
```